# Need To Host MVC Site as Subsite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webdeploy

- I have an MVC site with some javascript files and with some services.
- I try to host that as sub site in existing IIS site. By clicking add application option in IIS site.
- My actual Site Name "http://Testapp", Subsite Name: "http://Testapp/Subsite"
- The problem what I have is I try to call an service "/ControllerName/WebMothedname" from javascript through AJAX post.
- Because of Its hosted in subsite It try to hit the service URL as "http://Testapp/ControllerName/WebMothedname".
- But It should hit"http://Testapp/Subsite/ControllerName/WebMothedname"
- Same as the above issue some images referred in css also not able to access.

Comment: In IIS terms, it is called an application, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis There is no "subsite" in IIS.